# How can I load xml from a url instead of a file path in .NET?

Tags: .net, xml

We currently have code like this:

```
Dim xDoc = XDocument.Load(myXMLFilePath)
```

The only way we know how to do it currently is by using a file path and impersonation (since this file is on a secured network path).

I've looked at [XDocument.Load on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx), but I don't see anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using a WebRequest to get a stream and load the stream into the document.

Comment: I wonder what the difference in overhead is between opening a file over the network versus using a WebRequest...

Answer (score 4):

That very documentation says that the file parameter is "A URI string that references the file to load into a new XDocument." Furthermore, I have code that does exactly that---uses `XDocument.Load` with a URI.

Comment: And by URI, you specifically mean a URL and not a file path? I haven't had any luck passing in a URL to XDocument.Load().

Comment: Yes, my code definitely passes in a URL, of the "http://stuff" type. And it works. Not sure what to tell you if you don't have any luck... :-|.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Sample XML
<Product>
    <Name>Product1</Name>
    <Price>0.00</Price>
</Product>

    //Reading XML
    XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader("http://your-url");
    XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(rdr);

    //View the loaded contents
    //Response.ClearHeaders();
    //Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    //Response.Write(loaded);
    //Response.End();

    var data = from c in loaded.Descendants("Product")
            select new
            {
                name = c.Element("Name").Value,
            price = c.Element("Price").Value,
        };

    foreach (var element in data)
    {
        //Do something here
    }
```